# Можно ли добавить звездочки в сниппет выдачи google для главной страницы?

Tags: seo, google-search

Часто встречаю сниппет с рейтингом в поисковой выдаче гугла для статей и страниц товаров, но никогда не встречал для главной страницы.
Можно ли добавить звездочки в сниппет выдачи google для главной страницы?
Кто нибудь встречал такие страницы или есть какие-то ограничения со стороны гугла? Для сайта одностраничка продающего один товар это может быть полезно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть два варианта звёздочек: один на вашем скриншоте (рецензия), другой такой (число голосов): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bg27.png — уточните пожалуйста, какой именно вам нужен?

Comment: @andreymal число голосов. 2 вариант

Comment: Тогда AggregateRating (упомя́нут в ответе)

Answer (score 0):

Разумеется вы можете это делать. Вы можете это сделать с применением типа **[Review из Schema](http://schema.org/Review)**.

Однако в документации Гугл для структурированных данных типа **[Review](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review)**  есть некоторые уточнения/ограничения:

> Вы можете предоставлять рейтинги для следующих типов контента: ***Местные предприятия + Кинофильм + книги + Музыка + Продукты***.
>
> Удостоверьтесь, что отзывы и рейтинги, которые вы помечаете, легко доступны пользователям с отмеченной страницы. Пользователям должно быть сразу очевидно, что страница имеет обзор или рейтинг.

Таким образом вы не можете применять отзывы со сторонних веб-сайтов и отзывы не должны быть скрыты от пользователей, например в аккордеоне или в табе.

И обратите внимание на то, что свойство **author** есть требуемым. Это может быть персона или организация.

В соответствии с этим обратите внимание на следующее замечание Гугл:

> Имя одного рецензента должно быть действительным.

Кроме того в **[Общих руководящих принципах структурированных данных](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)** Гугл информирует, что структурированные данные должны представлять основное содержание веб-страницы.

Суммируя все вышеизложенное я могу следующим образом ответить на ваш вопрос:

Если главная страница имеет основное содержание как представление Местного предприятия или Кинофильма или книга или Музыка или какой-то Продукт (например уникальный и/или ручной работы), то вы можете создать разметку структурированных данных для главного типа как для одного из указанных и встроенную разметку для отзывов и для типа **[AggregateRating](https://schema.org/AggregateRating)**. При этом авторы отзывов должны иметь какую-то идентификацию, например линк профиля социальной сети, или линк веб-сайта или что-то подобной.